# Simple dual button bluetooth device with on/off switch, development advice

Tags: bluetooth

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction as I need to develop a simple 2 button bluetooth device that acts as a 2 character keyboard when paired.

( tried repurposing camera shutter devices but to no avail).

What would be teh best suggested development system and chipset for such a simple device ?

Thanks
Alan

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://www.espruino.com/BLE%20Keyboard

Comment: No that would be too expensive, was looking more for something like a remote shutter bluetooth device but instead of volume and enter it just emits a definable character instead